# How can we add a JTable to another JTable?

Tags: swing, jtable

Suppose I have a JTable with 10 rows and if I double click on a row, that row should be vanished and a new JTable should be inserted in that entire row.  I tried to insert the number of rows required, and I am removing the row selected by calling

```
((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).getDataVector().removeElementAt(row+insertedNumberOfRows)
```

Is there any other way to do add a JTable as a component in that entire row?

Comment: That sounds like an unusual requirement.  Can you justify why you want to do this, because there may be better ways of solving your problem if we had a better understanding of your problem.

Comment: Yes this is really unusual requirement. The actual table contains abstract data and if user wants to elaborate a single row information, clicks on a row. then in between two rows the new table should be displayed. Again if user clicks on the new table, the new table will be disappeared and the previous row should be displayed... it is just like a tree...

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a `JTable` inside another `JTable`. If you want to show a new child table (detail) when clicking on a row of the parent (master) table, listen the double-click in the cell, then remove the `JTable` from the containter panel, create the new one with the new rows to show and add to the container panel. Be careful with `pack()` and `validate()` as you remove and add components lively.